# How to mock usage of component in @value annotation of JPA request model?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, mocking, mockito

I have the following code, and I was wondering how to mock the component used in the value annotation. It is not instantiated in the model class, so I can't really use the annotation `@InjectMocks`, **how do I perform a mock in this context?**

```java
public interface Vehicule {
  @Value('#{target.VEHICULE_ID}')
  BigInteger getId();

  @Value('#{@mapperUtility.clobToString(target.CERTIFICATE)}') // How to mock this call?
  String getCertificate();
}

@Component
public class MapperUtility {
  public String clobToString(Clob clob) {
    return (clob == null) ? null : ClobType.INSTANCE.toString(clob); // from org.hibernate.type 
  }
}

public interface VehiculeRepository extends JpaRepository<Vehicule, String> {
  @Query(value = SQL_QUERY_FIND_VEHICULE_BY_IDS)
  List<Vehicule> findVehiculeByIds(@Param("Ids") List<BigInteger> ids);
}
```

What would a test that mocks the component inside the value annotation would look like?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common issue when using direct field injection. We solved this problem by writing a Junit5 extension: http://github.com/exabrial/mockito-object-injection

This allows you to cleanly inject data into private members of a class under test, without resorting to fire up an entire container for an integration test.

Example:

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ExtendWith({ MockitoExtension.class, InjectExtension.class })
class MyControllerTest {
 @InjectMocks
 private MyController myController;
 @Mock
 private Logger log;
 @Mock
 private Authenticator auther;
 @InjectionSource
 private Boolean securityEnabled;
 
 @Test
 void testDoSomething_secEnabled() throws Exception {
  securityEnabled = Boolean.TRUE;
  myController.doSomething();
  // wahoo no NPE! Test the "if then" half of the branch
 }
```

Comment: How does this work to mock the mapper utility? It's not just a value annotation, it uses a component inside the value annotation to process the value from the SQL record... How does your example apply to my scenario? I'm not sure to understand?